# Flutter - I am looking for a way to create a circle with icons positioned evenly on it

Tags: flutter

[The image shows the UI i want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfd17.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as Math;

const double _radiansPerDegree = Math.pi / 180;
final double _startAngle = -90.0 * _radiansPerDegree;

typedef double ItemAngleCalculator(int index);

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return new _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  final List<Widget> items = [
    new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: new MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: new Image.asset(
          'images/recycling.png',
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: new Image.asset(
        'images/gas-station.png',
        width: 60.0,
        height: 60.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: new Image.asset(
        'images/light-bulb.png',
        width: 60.0,
        height: 60.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: new Image.asset(
        'images/cflamp.png',
        width: 60.0,
        height: 60.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: new Image.asset(
        'images/plug.png',
        width: 60.0,
        height: 60.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.teal),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0,left: 20.0,right: 20.0),
              child: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [
                      new Color(0xFFA19D9A),
                      Colors.white,
                      new Color(0xFFA19D9A),
                    ]),
                    borderRadius:
                    new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(25.0))),
                child: new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      borderRadius:
                      new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(22.0))),
                  child: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      "Get recommendations by selecting any icon",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'CaviarDreams',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _buildStackView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildStackView() {
    final List<Widget> beverages = <Widget>[];
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double outerRadius = Math.min(width * 3 / 4, height * 3 / 4);
    double innerWhiteRadius = outerRadius * 3 / 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      beverages.add(_buildIcons(i));
    }

    return Flexible(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _drawCircle(outerRadius, Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.3)),
            _drawCircle(outerRadius - 25, Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2)),
            new CustomMultiChildLayout(
              delegate: new _CircularLayoutDelegate(
                itemCount: items.length,
                radius: outerRadius / 2,
              ),
              children: beverages,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/ask/capture");
                },
                child: Image.asset(
                  "images/earth-globe.png",
                  width: innerWhiteRadius,
                  height: innerWhiteRadius,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Draw a circle with given radius and color.
  Widget _drawCircle(double radius, Color color) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: color),
      width: radius,
      height: radius,
    );
  }



  Widget _buildIcons(int index) {
    final Widget item = items[index];

    return new LayoutId(
      id: 'BUTTON$index',
      child: item,
    );
  }
}

double _calculateItemAngle(int index) {
  double _itemSpacing = 360.0 / 5.0;
  return _startAngle + index * _itemSpacing * _radiansPerDegree;
}

class _CircularLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  static const String actionButton = 'BUTTON';

  final int itemCount;
  final double radius;

  _CircularLayoutDelegate({
    @required this.itemCount,
    @required this.radius,
  });

  Offset center;

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    center = new Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
      final String actionButtonId = '$actionButton$i';

      if (hasChild(actionButtonId)) {
        final Size buttonSize =
        layoutChild(actionButtonId, new BoxConstraints.loose(size));

        final double itemAngle = _calculateItemAngle(i);

        positionChild(
          actionButtonId,
          new Offset(
            (center.dx - buttonSize.width / 2) + (radius) * Math.cos(itemAngle),
            (center.dy - buttonSize.height / 2) +
                (radius) * Math.sin(itemAngle),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(_CircularLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      itemCount != oldDelegate.itemCount ||
          radius != oldDelegate.radius ;
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this UI in the image above using an implementation i found out but to no avail. Below is the image of what i want to achieve and the current code i have. If there is a best and efficient way to achieve this, i will be ver glad if i am pointed in that direction.

Comment: Instead of creating that UI element, you can just use that image and then use GestureDetector to execute specific functions for specific parts of that image. It'll feel just the same as in creating a UI element on your own, but with much lesser work.  But yeah, that's just my opinion

Comment: @rkdupr0n the image can't be used. It has to be built. Thank you though.

Comment: Hmm... Ok then. I've checked out ur code and I think I got the gist of it. Which part of it do ya have a problem with? If its that outer green ring connecting the outer icons, then I think I got a solution for that. Just use that _drawCircle to make that ring and then give each icon a container with circle shape and color of the container as the background color of the app. I tried to do that but realized all ur _drawCircles don't have full opacity, so it'll be a while for me to do it. But, if its anything else or ya need me to further explain this, I'll post it as an answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't change the code much, but I think I got the look of the UI you wanted. Check it out ;)

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as Math;

const double _radiansPerDegree = Math.pi / 180;
final double _startAngle = -90.0 * _radiansPerDegree;

typedef double ItemAngleCalculator(int index);

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return new _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Widget> items = [
    new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: new MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: new Image.asset(
          'assets/images/ball1.png',
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: new Image.asset(
          'assets/images/ball1.png',
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: new Image.asset(
          'assets/images/ball1.png',
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: new Image.asset(
          'assets/images/ball1.png',
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: new Image.asset(
          'assets/images/ball1.png',
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBody();
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [
                      new Color(0xFFA19D9A),
                      Colors.white,
                      new Color(0xFFA19D9A),
                    ]),
                    borderRadius:
                        new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(25.0))),
                child: new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      borderRadius:
                          new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(22.0))),
                  child: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      "Get recommendations by selecting any icon",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'CaviarDreams',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _buildStackView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildStackView() {
    final List<Widget> beverages = <Widget>[];
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double outerRadius = Math.min(width * 3 / 4, height * 3 / 4);
    double innerWhiteRadius = outerRadius * 3 / 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      beverages.add(_buildIcons(i));
    }

    return Flexible(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _drawCircle(outerRadius + 5, Colors.teal[100]),
            _drawCircle(outerRadius, Colors.white),
            _drawCircle(outerRadius / 2, Colors.teal[100]),
            _drawCircle((outerRadius - 40) / 2, Colors.teal),
            new CustomMultiChildLayout(
              delegate: new _CircularLayoutDelegate(
                itemCount: items.length,
                radius: outerRadius / 2,
              ),
              children: beverages,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/ask/capture");
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  size: 100,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Draw a circle with given radius and color.
  Widget _drawCircle(double outerRadius, Color color) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: color),
      width: outerRadius,
      height: outerRadius,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIcons(int index) {
    final Widget item = items[index];

    return new LayoutId(
      id: 'BUTTON$index',
      child: item,
    );
  }
}

double _calculateItemAngle(int index) {
  double _itemSpacing = 360.0 / 5.0;
  return _startAngle + index * _itemSpacing * _radiansPerDegree;
}

class _CircularLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  static const String actionButton = 'BUTTON';

  final int itemCount;
  final double radius;

  _CircularLayoutDelegate({
    @required this.itemCount,
    @required this.radius,
  });

  Offset center;

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    center = new Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
      final String actionButtonId = '$actionButton$i';

      if (hasChild(actionButtonId)) {
        final Size buttonSize =
            layoutChild(actionButtonId, new BoxConstraints.loose(size));

        final double itemAngle = _calculateItemAngle(i);

        positionChild(
          actionButtonId,
          new Offset(
            (center.dx - buttonSize.width / 2) + (radius) * Math.cos(itemAngle),
            (center.dy - buttonSize.height / 2) +
                (radius) * Math.sin(itemAngle),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(_CircularLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      itemCount != oldDelegate.itemCount || radius != oldDelegate.radius;
}
```

And this is the final output. P.S. I didn't have that image, so I used my own.
[image: Code Output]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your code out and give you my feedback.

Comment: Sure thing! And also, instead of using functions that return widgets, I recommend creating a new widget template and using that instead. It has better performance and stuff like hot reload works for that.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've been a life save. Please, one more thing.

Comment: What if you want the image with two texts below it in a column as a tile so you can loop through it for a list of that custom tile of the image and two texts in a listView, how can it be done. I tried it out and was having issues with constraining the size of the image but here is the case, i don't want to specify width and height for the image. One issue also has to do with ListView of the tile element in the overall ListView even though i setted shrinkWrap to true and physics to ScrollPhysics().

Comment: I'm afraid you've no option but to use a container. Be it column or listview, both get unbounded height and width unless bounded by the parent widget. But you can use mediaquery and set the container height and width to, say, 1/6 of the device width.

Comment: Okay. I will try this solution out. Thank you very much.

Comment: No probs dude :)